# Write an algorithm that tells me if two and only two numbers in three are the same

Tags: algorithm, math

Deceptively simple algorithm question I came across.  I'm trying to pull it off in 3 or less operations, and I'm reasonably convinced it can be solved with math, but I can't figure it out (and the source for the question didn't have an answer).

EDIT:

```
(a[0] == a[1] + a[0] == a[2] + a[1] == a[2]) == 1
```

is what I originally thought, but I'd like to see if it can be done in less operations (1 comparison being an operation).

Comment: What's the `n` in your `O(n)` estimation? Since the size of the array is constant, wouldn't any working algorithm necessarily run in constant time?

Comment: That is very true.  I'm looking for something that can do this in less then 4 operations (4 is the smallest I can get it with a naive approach).

Comment: Can you post your solution? What do you consider an operation?

Comment: Semi-joke answer: in Python, `return len(set(numbers)) == 2`. Three operations, if we assume `len` and `set` are each somehow carried out in a single instruction :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the 3 numbers are `a`, `b` and `c`,

```
(b == c) ? (a != c) : (a == b || a == c)
```

- If (a, b, c) = (1, 1, 1), then we will call `b == c` (true) and then `a != c` (false) and done.
- If (a, b, c) = (1, 1, 2), then we will call `b == c` (false) and then `a == b` (true) and done.
- If (a, b, c) = (1, 2, 1), then we will call `b == c` (false) and then `a == b` (false) and `a == c` (true) and done.
- If (a, b, c) = (2, 1, 1), then we will call `b == c` (true) and then `a != c` (true) and done.
- If (a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3), then we will call `b == c` (false) and then `a == b` (false) and `a == c` (false) and done.

So at most 3 comparison are performed.

There are also 2 conditional branching points at `?:` and `||` but OP does not count it.

Comment: I ended up with this but have an unnecessary comparison in mine.  I also didn't bother simplifying it past nested if statements.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you consider to be an "operation"...

The following uses only 3 comparisons out of the array. There is a forth comparison though, the `== 1` to ensure that there is exactly one match. I believe you could use a ton of branching to conditionally eliminate some of the comparisons, but if this is an optimization, the branching would probably make it perform worse.

There are exactly 3 outcomes:

- none of the values will be the same (sum is zero)
- two will be the same (sum is one)
- all three are the same (sum is three)

```
if (((array[0] == array[1]) +
     (array[1] == array[2]) +
     (array[0] == array[2])) == 1)
{
    // stuff
}
```

This trades comparisons with branching to achieve a maximum of 3 comparisons and a routes that only requires 2:

```
if (array[0] == array[1]) // if these are equal
    return !(array[1] == array[2]); // and these are not equal, return true
else
    return (array[0] == array[2]) || (array[1] == array[2]); // otherwise, if these are equal, we already know the others are not equal because we already tested them so return true
```

Comment: This is what I had.  I'm wondering though if it can be done in less operations.

Comment: 3 comparisons? There are 4 "=="'s.

Comment: yes, you're right I should be better with my terminology.  When I say operations I mean comparisons (4 =='s)

Comment: @KennyTM: I noticed that afterwards.  Also, depending on the type of the objects in the array, which may be expensive to compare, the integer compare may not amount to anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the expression:

```
((b == a) | (b == c)) ^ (a == c)
```

which has constant cost, always performs three comparisons and two logic operations. Having no branches, it ought to go easy on the processor.

Depending on the architecture,

```
((b == a) || (b == c)) ^ (a == c)
```

might be faster (this one performs two or three comparisons, one logic operation and one branch).

Answer (score 1):

My try...

```
return (ab ? (!ac) : (ac ? true : bc));
```

Where:

```
ab = (a==b)
ac = (a==c)
bc = (b==c)
```

This uses 2 or 3 comparisons, at the expense of conditional jumps sometimes. Let us check the number of operations on each case:

- **a == c == b:** (a==b) + jump + (a==c) + negation [returns a!=c] 4 operations
- **a == b != c:** the same as above, 4 operations
- **a != b == c:** (a==b) + jump + (a==c) + jump + (b==c) [returns this value] 5 operations
- **a == c != b:** (a==b) + jump + (a==c) + jump [returns true] 4 operations
- **a != c != b:** the same as above, 4 operations

Of course, this depends on your concept of operation... If jumps are not considered...